# onActivityResult - resultCode is always 0

Tags: android

I have problem with onActivityResult, whatever I'm doing I can't get resultCode right.

I know that there are similar questions but at the end they didn't help me and I couldn't fix it

**MainActivity:** method which will open new Activity *Popup.class*

```
public void openShopView(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Popup.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    b.putString("which", "ShopMain");
    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

**Second Activity:** method which will open yet another Activity *Popup.class* just with different layout

```
shop_c1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getIntent());
            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            b.putString("which", "ShopBuildings");
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

**Third Activity:** and there is method which should setResult and close Activity

```
building2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i("LOG_NEW: ", "" + getCurrentBuildingTable(1) + ", " + checkSlotTable(1));
            if(getCurrentBuildingTable(1) && checkSlotTable(1) == -1) {
                Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
                returnIntent.putExtra("result", 1);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }else if (checkSlotTable(1) == -1){
                Log.i("LOG_NEW: ", "Building already exist");
            }
            else{
                Log.i("LOG_NEW: ", "Not enough resources");
            }
        }
    });
```

At the end there is **onActivityResult()** from MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.i("LOG_RES: ", "Checking.. " + requestCode + ", " + resultCode);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
            Log.i("LOG_RES: ", result);

        }
    }
}
```

Whatever I'm doing I can't start *if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)* loop and resultCode is always 0..

Thanks for help

Comment: `setResult` must be called in **Second Activity**, since intent of second activity was passed in `startActivityForResult`

Comment: As @Saurabh says, result is received only from the activity that is launched with startActivityForResult.

Comment: @Saurabk
Thanks for answer, but is there any way to send to send result from third activity, or I should send result to second activity and from there to mainactivity ?

Comment: yes, 3rd > 2nd > 1st as I have written in answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setResult` must be called in **Second Activity**, since intent of second activity was passed in `startActivityForResult`.

However, you can delegate the result code of Third Activity to Second Activity, then to third.

Change your **Second Activity** to something like this:

```
shop_c1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getIntent());
                Bundle b = new Bundle();

                b.putString("which", "ShopBuildings");
                intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivityForResult(intent,1);
                //Remove finish from here
            }
        });
```

then also add this in **Second Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==1){
    setResult(resultCode,data);
    }

    finish();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working very well, u save me ;)
Just small note if anyone is interested I changed `returnIntent.putExtra("result", 1);`
to `returnIntent.putExtra("result", "1");` because of NullPointerException